# How to avoid nested using of bufio.Reader or bufio.Writer

Tags: go, buffer

I have a simple function which read something from a `io.Reader` into a byte slice:

```golang
func ReadSomething(r io.Reader) {
    bufReader := bufio.NewReader(r)
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    bufReader.Read(buf)
    ...
}
```

As you can see, to use buffered reading, it wraps the accepted `io.Reader` with `bufio.Reader`.

However, `bufio.Reader` itself is an implementation of `io.Reader` that can be accepted by this function. Since this function has no awareness of what exactly it received, it is possible to lead to nested using of `bufio.Reader`.

I have considered changing the type of `r` to `bufio.Reader` to forcibly ask upper levels to do the wrapping so my function can just use it as is, but since the wrapping can be a repeatedly work, I think it is better to leave it to lower levels.

Is there any good ideas to avoid nested using of `bufio.Reader` in my case?

Comment: The code in the question avoids unnecessary nesting. The [bufio.NewReader](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#NewReaderSize) documentation says: *If the argument io.Reader is already a [Reader](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Reader) with large enough size, it returns the underlying [Reader](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Reader).*

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thank you for clarifying this. I just have read [the source code of bufio.NewReader](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.22.0:src/bufio/bufio.go;l=59) and found it invokes `bufio.NewReader`. My question makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check [the source for `bufio.NewReader()`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.22.0:src/bufio/bufio.go;l=59) you will find that this is already taken care of.

`NewReader()` calls `NewReaderSize()` with the default buffer size (4096 bytes).  `NewReaderSize()` checks to see if the `io.Reader` to be read is already a `bufio.Reader`.  If it is, and if the buffer size on that buffered reader is at least as large as the desired size then instead of wrapping a `bufio.Reader` around the `io.Reader`, it just returns the `io.Reader` itself.

i.e. `NewReader()` will only nest a `bufio.Reader` around another `bufio.Reader` if the reader to be nested has a buffer size smaller than the default (4096 bytes), to avoid returning a buffered reader with a smaller buffer than asked for.

This is [mentioned in the documentation, but only for `NewReaderSize()`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#NewReader); it also applies to `NewReader()` though this is not explicitly documented but is evident in the code.